# Mkdir permission doesn't set correct

Tags: php

I use this code to make folder in web site.

```
mkdir("folder/folder",0744,true);
```

But in practical "folder" permission is 600.

what's problem?

Comment: Did you enable `error_reporting` yet? Add missing infos: surrounding folder and permission structure, Apache and PHP uid.

Comment: check your [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php). Try `umask(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode may be affected by your current umask. 
Do something like this:

```
$old_umask = umask(0); 
mkdir('folder/folder', 0744);
umask($old_umask);
```